# No muestra el valor si tiene acento {{ ucwords(strtolower($user->name)) }}

Tags: php

Tengo este código que no muestra el valor de la variable si tiene acento ó quizás cualquier otro caracter, solo he probado con acento `{{ ucwords(strtolower($user->name)) }}`

Comment: Ese codigo solo esta dandole mayusculas y minusculas a una variable. Falta reconocer un ejemplo de dicha variable, como por ejemplo al imprimir solo $user->name

Comment: En vez de `strtolower()` deberías usar [`mb_strtolower()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mb-strtolower.php) porque supongo que tus datos son multibyte (UTF-#)

Comment: Los usuarios escribe de manera diferente, necesito llevar a Camel Case todas, ejemplo: María (Tiene acento) ANDREA (Todo en Mayúsculas) funciona pero en nombre de María desaparece porque tiene acento.

Comment: Muchas gracias Triby, funcionó... No conocía esa función

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta de Triby es la solución: En vez de strtolower() deberías usar mb_strtolower() porque supongo que tus datos son multibyte (UTF-#)

Comment: recuerda marcar la respuesta para cerrar el tema

Comment: Debo esperar dos días

Comment: cierto, es tuya al ponerla acá